# Can I work with multiple working directories in R?

Tags: r, file, directory

Can I work with parallel working directories in R, or can I change the working directory in a loop to access the files from different folders?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I find it easier to have a single working directory. You find out what that is using the

```
getwd()
```

function. Typically, my working directory is something like:

```
~/colin/project1/R
```

You can change your working directory using

```
setwd()
```

You can easily access other files using the full path. In particular, I find

```
##List files in current directory
list.files()
##Give full path 
list.files(full.names=TRUE)
##list files in the species1 directory
list.files("species1/", full.names=TRUE)
```

very handy.

Comment: thnks for the suggestion but for me problem is that I have three different folders containing species' files. All three folders have same number of files with similar names. These three folders represents different experimental conditions and I want to compare these files in a loop.

Comment: That doesn't cause a problem. See my updated `list.files` call where I specify a directory.

Comment: I tried your suggestion of using list.files("species1/",full.names=TRUE), but it seems if I use more than one path, e.g. sp_folder1<-list.files("species1/",full.names=TRUE)
and, sp_folder2<-list.files("species2/",full.names=TRUE)
I cannot get the files from sp_folder2 in a nested for loop.
can you help me or in nested loop I cannot do that. Thanks

Comment: @mariariaz YOu should ask a new question.

Answer (score 3):

Don't change the working directory in a loop, loop over the directories and use `file.path` to get to the file you want. Something like:

```
for(path in c("data1","data2","data3")){
  for(file in c("file1.txt","file2.txt")){
     fullPath = file.path(path,file)
     doSomethingWith(fullPath)
     }
  }
```

That will loop over `data1/file1.txt`, `data1/file2.txt` and so on. Note it will also handle differences between path separators in different operating systems - don't try and paste file path components together with `paste` because you'll get it wrong.

Comment: Thanks you, just to be very sure before using it. I have over 100 species treated in three different experimental conditions. In each experiments I have data of 12 months (12 columns with 10 observations). Now, in first step, I want to see what are the months in first experiment where species performed poorely (by comparing the observed values with a standard value) and in second step want to see the difference of second and third experiment of the same month of first experiment where species performed poorley.

Comment: I would write a function that had as arguments the species, the condition and returned the full file path for that data. Then another function that read that data in. Then a function that compared the data. And so on. A bit complex for this comment. Try making your problem a bit more concrete and posting a new question.